# Entity framework gives error underlying provider failed on open

Tags: entity-framework

I developed a web site on my local pc and local database using entity framework, Now I gave all the code to my client now the entity framework gives an error underlying provider failed on open I modified data source, initial catalog, user id and password of the connection string of entity framework but of no use please help. below is my connection string.

```
<add name="SBV_dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SBVEntityModel.csdl|res://*/SBVEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/SBVEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=yagnesh_db;user id=yagnesh;password=yagnesh@123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use like below.Give a connection string to the SQL server is as below (This is a sample code).

```
<add name="ContextName" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBCatalogName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**e.g.**

```
<add name="PawLoyalty" connectionString="Server=.;database=PawLoyalty;Trusted_connection=true;pooling=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks Sampath for your help. I don't know if this will work but what I did is.. I opened my .edmx file right click it and then I clicked 'Update Model from Database' this took me to update wizard where I passed the right information and that solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Yagnesh.Dixit nice to hear that you have solved your problem.Great.